# How can I mock with Typescript the Express Request, Response and NextFunction objects

Tags: typescript, jestjs

This is my middlewares:

```
export const isLogged = () => (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => next();
```

I'm trying to create a unit test but I'm unable to mock with the correct types:

```
const middleware = middlewares.isLogged()

middleware(
  jest.fn<Request>(), // Expected 0-2 type argument but got 1
  jest.fn<Response>(),
  jest.fn<NextFunction>(),
);
```

This is not working, I've tried mocking the `express` module and such but haven't gotten it to work. How can I mock them?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The first two arguments are a `Request` object and a `Response` object.

Since your code doesn't use `req` or `res` you can just pass empty objects as mocks and tell TypeScript to treat the mocks as the expected types using `as`:

```ts
it('should call next', () => {
  const next = jest.fn();
  middleware(
    {} as Request,
    {} as Response,
    next,
  );
  expect(next).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
});
```

**Update**

If you want to mock additional properties on `Request` or `Response` then you can simply add these to your mock object.

Your mock object will (probably) not implement the full `Request` or `Response` interface so you can either use something like `Partial<Request>` or `Partial<Response>`, or simply tell TypeScript you want ["to opt-out of type-checking and let the values pass through compile-time checks"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) by using the type `any` for the mock objects:

```ts
it('should call next', () => {
  const req: any = {
    get: jest.fn((name) => {
      if (name === 'content-type') return 'text/plain';
    })
  };
  const res: any = {
    send: jest.fn()
  }
  const next = jest.fn();
  middleware(
    req,
    res,
    next,
  );
  expect(next).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
});
```

Comment: how would I go about mocking `req.get()` function?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco  I updated my answer to include mocking properties on `req` and `res`

Comment: declaring the mock as `req :any` did the trick. I hadn't tried it before cause my middleware local parameter has it typed as `req: Request` but it seems it works anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you please post a complete example? E.g. I'm not sure where middleware coming from.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Utility Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) from Typescript. Like:

```
const middleware = middlewares.isLogged()

const req: Partial<Request> = {};
const res: Partial<Response> = {};
const next: NextFunction = jest.fn();

middleware(req, res, next);
```